# How to check the number of day of month?

Tags: bash, date

I want a bash script to check if today is 15<sup>th</sup> of the current month?

```
if [ $dayOfMonth == 15 ]
then
  echo "15th day of month
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

The day of the month may be had from the command `date +%d`, which calls the `date` command with a format string `%d`.  That format string is possibly described in the `date` manual, but definitely in the manual for the `strftime()` C function.  It gives you the day of the month as a two digit (possibly zero-filled) number.

You can use that in your test:

```bsh
day=$( date +%d )

if [ "$day" = "15" ]; then
   echo 'the 15th'
fi
```

Note the quoting used here and that tests for equality between strings is done with a single `=` in `[ ... ]` tests.

In recent releases of the `bash` shell (4.2+), which is what I presume you are actually using, you may also get the day of the month with

```bsh
printf -v day '%(%d)T' -1
```

This sets the variable `day` to the day of the current month, without relying on the external `date` command. The `-1` signifies the current date and time, [see the description in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-printf).

Comment: You might want to use `%(%-d)T` so the result is not zero-padded (avoiding invalid octal numbers 08 and 09)

Comment: @glennjackman Believe it or not, but that produces `-d` on my OpenBSD system. I believe it's dependent on the native C library, and non-Linux systems may not have the `%-d` format (it's not standard). However, I decided to use a string comparison here, so the issue with invalid octal numbers would not arise.

Comment: On my Mac `/bin/date -j -f '%Y-%m-%d' 2021-03-08 '+%d,%_d,%-d'` outputs `08, 8,8` and I don't have a real *BSD system to test on.

Comment: @glennjackman, in any case, `[`'s arithmetic operators treat operands as decimal even if they start with `0`. You'd only have the problem if you used `[[ $day -eq 9 ]]` or `(( day == 9 ))` or `let day==9`

Comment: The workaround of BSD not having a `%-d` format is to tell bash to interpret the number as decimal (even if it starts with a zero): `a=09; [[ "10#$a" -eq 9 ]] && echo yes`. That should give you bash portable code (to BSD).

Comment: @Isaac Or you could just compare strings, which does not require `bash`, which is what I'm currently doing.  I'm noting that this is also what the user is doing in the question.

Comment: A text test demands that you write `"09"` on the right hand side of the test (to test for number `9`) which the user might (or not) know. And the user is mixing `[` with `==`, so it is also bash centric. In any case, this is probably a corner case, so, don't worry, keep on. :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ date --help
Usage: date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
…
  %d   day of month (e.g., 01)
…
```

Thus, using string equality (which requires a leading zero for numbers up to 9, e.g. `= "09"`):

```sh
if [ "$(date +%d)" = "15" ]; then …
```

Or using numeric equality (which does not require a leading zero, you can write e.g. `-eq 9`):

```sh
if [ "$(date +%d)" -eq 9 ]; then …
```

Beware that in bash, `[[ $(date +%d) -eq 9 ]]` does not work, because when you use `-eq` in double brackets rather than single brackets, it treats a leading zero as indicating that the number is in octal. Similarly, if you use arithmetic expressions, all shells treat leading zeros as indicating an octal number, so something like `(($(date +%d) == 9))` does not work. (`(($(date +%d) == 15))` would work, but would display an error message on the 8th and 9th of the month.) `dayOfMonth=$(date +%d); dayOfMonth=${dayOfMonth#0}; ((d == 9))` would work because in the case of the day of the month, there is only one leading 0.

Comment: zsh and mksh don't treat numbers with leading 0s as octal by default. You need to enable the `octalzeroes`  option in `zsh` and the `posix` option in `mksh`. `yash` and `ksh93` don't have a problem with 08 nor 09. They are just interpreted as decimal since they can obviously not be octals.